# Though my program runs, the variables(age and favourite_number) are not highlighted and in the problem section it highlights a problem

Tags: c, linux, variables, visual-studio-code

`#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

```
char firstInitial , lastInitial;
int age , favourite_number;

printf("Enter Initial character of your name : \n");
scanf(" %c" ,&firstInitial );

printf("Enter initial character of your surname :  \n");
scanf(" %c" , &lastInitial);

printf("Enter your age : \n");
scanf(" %d",&age);

printf("Enter your favourite number : \n");
scanf(" %d",&favourite_number);

printf("Your name is %c.%c. and your age is %d.\n", firstInitial , lastInitial ,age);
printf("Your favourite number is %d \n", favourite_number);


return 0;
```

}`[There is an error mentioned in the problem section even though I have put the semicolon and the program runs.
Why are the variables not highlighted?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkZIe.png)

Comment: It should be some bugs are before line 17. We can't tell what is it tho.

Comment: Please don't post _images_ of code and _especially_ not _links_ to images of code. Please _edit_ your question and post your [representative] code [as text] in a code block here.